# ijavascript will not install

Tags: anaconda, zeromq, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have been trying to run Javascript from a Jupyter Notebook on Windows 10 but failed miserably. It seems I cannot install IJavascript to make it available.

All installation guides say to use Anaconda for IJavascript - so I did, but I CANNOT FIND IJAVASCRIPT anywhere within Anaconda, only the js packages, i searched everywhere there was a search bar available. So, because I am stubborn i tried the hard way:

Installed **all** javascript packages except mocha (which cannot be found) listed here:
https://anaconda.org/javascript/repo

then tried
npm install -g ijavascript
but keep getting this error:

```
c:\users\ryuuzako\anaconda3\scripts\node_modules\ijavascript\node_modules\nan\nan_json.h(89): error C2660: 'v8::JSON::P
arse': function does not take 2 arguments [C:\Users\ryuuzako\Anaconda3\Scripts\node_modules\ijavascript\node_modules\ze
romq\build\zmq.vcxproj]
```

"Javascript" type does not appear when creating a new file in Jupyter, my guess is because ijavascript is not installed..

ANY suggestion to make it work is greatly appreciated.
I can provide the whole npm log but it is humongous.

Feel free to assume i am a complete idiot who didn't work with node before.

Comment: Have you managed to get this working yet?

Answer (score 5):

I've just forked **ijavascript** and edited the documentation for the [Windows installation section](https://github.com/joeflack4/ijavascript/blob/pr_docs-installation-section-update/README.md#windows) as shown below.

---

#### Windows

Install [Python3](https://www.python.org/downloads/) or the [Anaconda3](http://continuum.io/downloads) Python distribution.

In the command line:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip3 install jupyter
npm install -g ijavascript
ijsinstall
```

If the `ijinstall` command is not recognized, you can execute it manually by navigating to your npm install directory and running the `ijinstall` batch file. If you do not know where your npm install is located, try looking for it in the default install location: `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm`.

Then you can run `jupyter notebook` in your terminal to load Jupyter Notebook. When you create a new Jupyter Notebook, you should see the Javascript (Node) kernel available.

If using the [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads) alternative to the standard [Python distribution](https://www.python.org/downloads/), it comes pre-installed with Jupyter Notebook. If using Anaconda, you can skip the `pip3 install jupyter` step.

---

This picture might also help, when it comes to the `ijinstall` part.
[image]

Comment: Right now this works with nodejs v8 but not nodejs v10. This is because a dependency (zeromq v4) needs binaries to be made available. It is possible to manually compile these binaries if you want to use nodejs v10 but I reverted to nodejs v8 instead. See https://github.com/n-riesco/ijavascript/issues/184

Comment: but `npm` insists it require `python 2.7` to continue

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this as well. After installing by running commands:

```
pip install jupyter
npm install -g ijavascript
```

You will need to update the environment variable named 'Path' in the 'System Variables' section.
[image]

In Windows 10, Python 3.10, the path to add looks like:

```
C:\Users\your-windows-user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts
```

***After changing the environment variable, you will need to re-start the computer for it to take effect.***

Once this is done, run:

```
ijsinstall
```

in the command prompt and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

This also happeed to me.

First thing install anaconda after that(by default you have installed jupyter),
then search in your menu apps for anaconda prompt, then install ijavascript from anaconda prompt:

```
npm install -g ijavascript
ijsinstall
```

then run jupyter from anaconda prompt

```
jupyter notebook
```